# Windows 7 Keyboard shortcuts switch unexpectedly

Tags: windows-7

Does anyone know why my keyboard would suddenly start mapping the "D" button to the "WINDOWS+M" shortcut, and do a bunch of other different keyboard mappings?  The only thing that seems to resolve this is a reboot of my computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Win+M</kbd> and <kbd>Win+D</kbd> have very similar results.  Your <kbd>D</kbd> may be remapped to <kbd>Win+D</kbd>.

I have seen many times various modifier keys getting stuck.  If there's a lot going on on your computer, keys can become stuck, not physically but mentally as far as the compter remembers.  It remembers you pressing the key, but missed the point where you released the key, so it thinks it's still pressed.

Press each <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd> once each to reset their state.  I've also had to do the same for Arrow keys in the past, particularly when playing games.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Indeed it seems that my Windows key was stuck, either mentally or physically.  I resolved this by using an external keyboard.