# Windows enters horrible shortcut mode where every key triggers an action - why? How do I stop it?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remote desktop pressing Windows key randomly](https://superuser.com/questions/5480/remote-desktop-pressing-windows-key-randomly)
>   [Windows 7 Keyboard shortcuts switch unexpectedly](https://superuser.com/questions/357072/windows-7-keyboard-shortcuts-switch-unexpectedly)

Periodically, I hit some secret keyboard shortcut that causes windows to enter a super-duper shortcut mode where pressing e opens explorer, and nearly everything else does too. It's a bit like Windows-key lock mode. The only way to fix it is to restart the computer.

What is this mode, how did I get into it, and how do I get out of it?

Comment: That may be some kind of 'helpful' software provided by the computer manufacturer, rather than a Windows feature. Maybe check their documentation.

Comment: afraid not, this has happened to me on many different computers (and many versions of windows)! I think it's some kind of accessability thing.

Comment: The answer at http://superuser.com/questions/357072/windows-7-keyboard-shortcuts-switch-unexpectedly looks like the answer I was thinking of for this.  Basically, the key got bumped, but Windows missed the "release" event on it, so it thinks it's still held down.  Pressing the key again gives Windows another chance to capture the event so it realizes the key's not still being held.

Comment: i've tried this when it happens. pressing keys doesn't fix the issue, i have to restart

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your Windows key got stuck.  Try giving it a few firm taps, that normally releases it.

Comment: restarting the computer fixes the problem - that, and the fact that I've tried that before make me pretty sure it isn't that